# When can we say an algorithm is parameter free?

Tags: algorithms, parameter-estimation, stochastic-approximation

I was reading the paper by Dr. Francesco at http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.3816. The author presented a kernel version of parameter-free algorithm. But, any kernel, AFAIK, takes some parameter(RBF bandwidth, polynomial degree etc. which needs to be properly tuned for better results). In this spirit, How can the algorithm in this paper be called "parameter-free"?

Comment: Did you read the second-to-last paragraph of the introduction, on page 2? The author explains that (roughly), the algorithm does not require parameters that depend on the data (and thus would need to be tuned).

Comment: Then why he uses the statement "with no parameters to tune nor the need for cross-validation" in second-to last para on page 2. My Q is how can one claim that their algorithm is parameter-free, despite having some parameter to learn. As you might be well aware that algo in this paper is trying to eliminate the need of cross-validation by making algo parameter-free but somewhere it needs to tune some parameter/ hyper parameter

Comment: In case my last sentence is not clear: they have *no* parameters to learn, AFAIK. The parenthesis refers to the fact that they do *not* "require parameters that [..] would need to be tuned".

Comment: Agreed. That they don't require parameters that depend on the data. e.g. learning rate. My Q in the title is more general and asking for clarification if there are parameters/hyper-parameters in the algorithm, is the use of of the term "parameter-free" justified? Alternatively, author can say "near parameter-free" something like that. Because of using strong statement like that used by Dr. Francesco is confusing.

Comment: Looking at his algorithm, ther *are* parameters, athough they do not depend on the data (and just basically seem to impact the guarantee you get, in terms of performance and running time (?)). One thing to keep in mind, though, is that in any publication there is a "PR factor": you want to advertise your results, by arguing that they have the nice property people were looking for... in this case, 'parameter-freeness' in terms of the data. The reader may not go past the abstract or intro, so you need to make that point explicit, even if it's technically a bit more subtle.

Comment: Thanks @ClementC. That washes my doubt. BTW, I remember you meeting at Symposium on Learning algorithms in IISc Bangalore In Jan during poster presentation.